# processing this string with php

Tags: php, string

I have a text string that looks like this

```
var1=red&var2=green&var3=blue&var4=magenta
```

How can manipulate this string isolate the value of `var2` which in this case is `green`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)  What you have looks close enough to an URL param string that you might as well use the built in methods for handling URLs.

Answer (score 7):

Use the php function [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 3):

```
parse_str($str, $vars);
echo $vars['var2'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
parse_str($str,$tmp);
// $tmp['var2'] is now what you're looking for
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_str` function to parse the string into an array / variables. In this case I prefer outputting to array instead of variables to prevent the pollution of namespace.

```
<?php

$str = 'var1=red&var2=green&var3=blue&var4=magenta';

parse_str($str, $output);

$result = null;
foreach($output as $k => $v){
    if($v == 'green'){
        $result = $k;
        break;
    }
}

?>
```